# Visa Token Service (VTS)

Tags: java

Has any body sent the request to Visa token Service with valid encryption?

https://developer.visa.com/products/vts/reference#vts__payment_data

Was able to pass XPAY TOKEN genration, please help in JWE in code:

```
public static String generateJWE3(PlainPan pan) throws Exception {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(pan);

    String sharedSecret = Constants.VTS_SHARED_SECRET;
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] digest = md.digest(sharedSecret.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    String kid = "gUkXp2s5v8y/A?D(G+KbPeShVmYq3t6w";

    KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    kg.init(256);

    String encryptionKey = Constants.VTS_API_KEY;

    JWEAlgorithm jweAlgorithm = JWEAlgorithm.A256GCMKW;
    EncryptionMethod encryptionMethod = EncryptionMethod.A256GCM;

    JWEHeader.Builder headerBuilder = new JWEHeader.Builder(jweAlgorithm, encryptionMethod);

    headerBuilder.keyID(encryptionKey);

    JWEHeader header = headerBuilder.build();
    JWEEncrypter encrypter = new AESEncrypter(digest);

    encrypter.getJCAContext().setProvider(BouncyCastleProviderSingleton.getInstance());
    JWEObject jweObject = new JWEObject(header, new Payload(json));
    jweObject.encrypt(encrypter);

    String serialized = jweObject.serialize();
    JWEObject temp = JWEObject.parse(serialized);

    System.out.println("In JWE Header= " + temp.getHeader());
    System.out.println("In Enc Key= " + temp.getEncryptedKey());
    System.out.println("In IV= " + temp.getIV());
    System.out.println("In CT= " + temp.getCipherText());
    System.out.println("In AT= " + temp.getAuthTag());

    //  decrypt(sharedSecret,serialized);

    return serialized;
}
```

```
{
  "errorResponse":{
    "status":400,
    "message":"Input for encPaymentInstrument is invalid or inconsistent with the profile.",
    "reason":"invalidParameter",
    "details":[{
      "location":"encPaymentInstrument"
    }]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because of the Invalid `encPaymentInstrument` data please ask the user to follow the below steps,

Steps To make the API call:

- Create VTS APP
- go to the registered gmail to check the email from VTS
- navigate to that URL (https://developer.digital.visa.com/self-service-ic) set password and create a profile, the value given for APPID field will be the “clientAppID”
- Please use `nimbus-jose-jwt-4.12.jar` utility to generate jwe encryption.